# Json 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, json

I have a json list like this:

```
{
  "usuarios": [
 {
  "id": 1,
  "nome": "vitor",
  "email": "vitor@"
   }
  ]
}
```

And I try to list this items using Python like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import requests
import json
import sys

def list_users():
   response = json.loads(requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:3000/usuarios/")._content)    
   for r in response.get("usuarios"):
       print r["id"],r["nome"],r['email']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    list_users()
```

And when I run, appear this error:

```
   python rest_cli.py 
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "rest_cli.py", line 62, in <module>
   listar_usuarios()
   File "rest_cli.py", line 10, in listar_usuarios
   for r in response.get("usuarios"):
   AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: print `response` before looping and post that here

Comment: `response` is apparently a list, so it has not `get` method like you try to use in `response.get("usuarios")`. Instead, probably `for r in response: ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URL in the following code is already giving you an array as `response`.

```
response = json.loads(requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:3000/usuarios/")._content)
```

Don't do a `get` on the `response`. Just use a simple `for loop` on it like :

```
for r in response:
       print r["id"],r["nome"],r['email']
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a namespace issue as you are importing everything from requests I believe. Remove the .get and just use requests.
requests("http://127.0.0.1:3000/usuarios/")._content